# How to org-export this tag into HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, right-to-left

**how to export `dir="rtl"` into HTML file from an org buffer?**

TL;DR:
I want to export this simple org-buffer written in Arabic into HTML. The direction should be from right to left. I have this setting in `.emacs` relevant to the language just to enable writing from right to left in org-mode, but this is only a convenient way for writing and should not be necessary to try out the MWE below, so feel free to skip this setting if you want:

```
;; for right-to-left direction in org-mode
(defun set-bidi-env ()
  "interactive"
  (setq bidi-paragraph-direction 'nil))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'set-bidi-env)
```

**MWE**

```
#+TITLE: العنوان بالعربية
#+AUTHOR: اسم المؤلف
#+EMAIL: username@accountname.com
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil
#+LANGUAGE: ar
#+ATTR_HTML: :dir rtl
#+CREATOR: Emacs 25.1.50.2 (Org mode 8.3.4)

* تعريف بالارقام الهندية او الشرقية ١، ٢، ٣

** النقطة الاولى

** الثانية

** الثالثة

** وهكذا
* النهاية

#+CAPTION: المواد المطلوبة
#+NAME: tab:items

| تسلسل | المادة  | العدد      |
|-------+---------+------------|
| ١     | طحين    | ٥ كيلوغرام |
| ٢     | رز      | ٣ كيلوغرام |
| ٣     | بطيخ    | ٢ كيلوغرام |
| ٤     | قرنابيط | ٢ كيلوغرام |
|-------+---------+------------|
```

To export org-buffer into HTML and open it in the default browser, one has to hit: <kbd>C-c C-e h o</kbd>

The exported `.html` file should be generated in the working directory:

**Exported HTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar"><!-- change here! -->
<head>
<!-- 2016-04-08 Fri 10:52 -->
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>العنوان بالعربية</title>
<meta  name="generator" content="Org-mode" />
<meta  name="author" content="اسم المؤلف" />
<style type="text/css">
 <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
  .title  { text-align: center;
             margin-bottom: .2em; }
  .subtitle { text-align: center;
              font-size: medium;
              font-weight: bold;
              margin-top:0; }
  .todo   { font-family: monospace; color: red; }
  .done   { font-family: monospace; color: green; }
  .priority { font-family: monospace; color: orange; }
  .tag    { background-color: #eee; font-family: monospace;
            padding: 2px; font-size: 80%; font-weight: normal; }
  .timestamp { color: #bebebe; }
  .timestamp-kwd { color: #5f9ea0; }
  .org-right  { margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0px;  text-align: right; }
  .org-left   { margin-left: 0px;  margin-right: auto; text-align: left; }
  .org-center { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; }
  .underline { text-decoration: underline; }
  #postamble p, #preamble p { font-size: 90%; margin: .2em; }
  p.verse { margin-left: 3%; }
  pre {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #eee;
    padding: 8pt;
    font-family: monospace;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1.2em;
  }
  pre.src {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 1.2em;
  }
  pre.src:before {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    top: -10px;
    right: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  pre.src:hover:before { display: inline;}
  pre.src-sh:before    { content: 'sh'; }
  pre.src-bash:before  { content: 'sh'; }
  pre.src-emacs-lisp:before { content: 'Emacs Lisp'; }
  pre.src-R:before     { content: 'R'; }
  pre.src-perl:before  { content: 'Perl'; }
  pre.src-java:before  { content: 'Java'; }
  pre.src-sql:before   { content: 'SQL'; }

  table { border-collapse:collapse; }
  caption.t-above { caption-side: top; }
  caption.t-bottom { caption-side: bottom; }
  td, th { vertical-align:top;  }
  th.org-right  { text-align: center;  }
  th.org-left   { text-align: center;   }
  th.org-center { text-align: center; }
  td.org-right  { text-align: right;  }
  td.org-left   { text-align: left;   }
  td.org-center { text-align: center; }
  dt { font-weight: bold; }
  .footpara { display: inline; }
  .footdef  { margin-bottom: 1em; }
  .figure { padding: 1em; }
  .figure p { text-align: center; }
  .inlinetask {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #ffffcc;
  }
  #org-div-home-and-up
   { text-align: right; font-size: 70%; white-space: nowrap; }
  textarea { overflow-x: auto; }
  .linenr { font-size: smaller }
  .code-highlighted { background-color: #ffff00; }
  .org-info-js_info-navigation { border-style: none; }
  #org-info-js_console-label
    { font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap; }
  .org-info-js_search-highlight
    { background-color: #ffff00; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; }
  /*]]>*/-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
@licstart  The following is the entire license notice for the
JavaScript code in this tag.

Copyright (C) 2012-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

The JavaScript code in this tag is free software: you can
redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU
General Public License (GNU GPL) as published by the Free Software
Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option)
any later version.  The code is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY;
without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU GPL for more details.

As additional permission under GNU GPL version 3 section 7, you
may distribute non-source (e.g., minimized or compacted) forms of
that code without the copy of the GNU GPL normally required by
section 4, provided you include this license notice and a URL
through which recipients can access the Corresponding Source.


@licend  The above is the entire license notice
for the JavaScript code in this tag.
*/
<!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/
 function CodeHighlightOn(elem, id)
 {
   var target = document.getElementById(id);
   if(null != target) {
     elem.cacheClassElem = elem.className;
     elem.cacheClassTarget = target.className;
     target.className = "code-highlighted";
     elem.className   = "code-highlighted";
   }
 }
 function CodeHighlightOff(elem, id)
 {
   var target = document.getElementById(id);
   if(elem.cacheClassElem)
     elem.className = elem.cacheClassElem;
   if(elem.cacheClassTarget)
     target.className = elem.cacheClassTarget;
 }
/*]]>*///-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">العنوان بالعربية</h1>

<div id="outline-container-orgheadline5" class="outline-2">
<h2 id="orgheadline5">تعريف بالارقام الهندية او الشرقية ١، ٢، ٣</h2>
<div class="outline-text-2" id="text-orgheadline5">
</div><div id="outline-container-orgheadline1" class="outline-3">
<h3 id="orgheadline1">النقطة الاولى</h3>
</div>

<div id="outline-container-orgheadline2" class="outline-3">
<h3 id="orgheadline2">الثانية</h3>
</div>

<div id="outline-container-orgheadline3" class="outline-3">
<h3 id="orgheadline3">الثالثة</h3>
</div>

<div id="outline-container-orgheadline4" class="outline-3">
<h3 id="orgheadline4">وهكذا</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div id="outline-container-orgheadline6" class="outline-2">
<h2 id="orgheadline6">النهاية</h2>
<div class="outline-text-2" id="text-orgheadline6">
<table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" rules="groups" frame="hsides">


<colgroup>
<col  class="org-left" />

<col  class="org-left" />

<col  class="org-left" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="org-left">تسلسل</th>
<th scope="col" class="org-left">المادة</th>
<th scope="col" class="org-left">العدد</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="org-left">١</td>
<td class="org-left">طحين</td>
<td class="org-left">٥ كيلوغرام</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="org-left">٢</td>
<td class="org-left">رز</td>
<td class="org-left">٣ كيلوغرام</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="org-left">٣</td>
<td class="org-left">بطيخ</td>
<td class="org-left">٢ كيلوغرام</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="org-left">٤</td>
<td class="org-left">قرنابيط</td>
<td class="org-left">٢ كيلوغرام</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="postamble" class="status">
<p class="author">تأليف: اسم المؤلف</p>
<p class="date">Created: 2016-04-08 Fri 10:52</p>
<p class="validation"><a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">Validate</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**
[image]

Now everything was exported as expected except for the direction! If I want to change direction from INSIDE the generated html file, I have to change one line (marked in the code above) to this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar", dir="rtl"><!-- change here -->
```

Now when I hit <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> from inside the edited html buffer, it will be  correctly displayed in browser from right to left. So it seems that all I need is to tell org-mode to export this little parameter `dir="rtl"` and everything will be just fine.

**Output -- the desired one**
[image]

In org manual, I found `#+ATTR_HTML:` but my trial of `#+ATTR_HTML: :dir rtl` was unsuccessful, my question to org-mode users how to export this html parameter from org buffer *correctly*?

**Update**

as amitp pointed out, this is my best solution for time being just put this in th org mode file:

```
#+HTML: <style> body {direction: rtl} </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source file `ox-html.el`, the function `org-html-template` does not seem to allow customizing the `<html...>` or `<body>` tags in the export. :( However, there's also a CSS property [direction:rtl](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/) that you could use, since org-mode lets you change the CSS by setting

```
(setq org-html-head "<style> <![CDATA[ body { direction: rtl; } ]]> </style>")
```

I am not sure if CDATA should be there; the `org-html-head` docstring shows it in the example. Alternatively, try it without:

```
(setq org-html-head "<style> body { direction: rtl; } </style>")
```

Comment: thanks! this worked when I tried the one without `CDATA`. What I need is to change direction from within the `.org` file and not from the dot emacs file globally. Moreover, sometimes I write `rtl` and then `ltr` in the same buffer so would be useful if the solution can be extended to enable direction change back and forth within the org buffer.

Comment: For that I think you can write `#+begin_html`…`#+end_html` somewhere in the org file, with `<style> body { direction: rtl; } </style>` inside.

Comment: thanks, this works now from inside org file, I found that `#+HTML: <style> body { direction: rtl; } </style>` works too. But still changing direction back and forth in the document remains a mystery to me.

Comment: In theory, you can use the CSS to apply to any portion of the document by using a CSS selector other than `body`. In practice, org export makes this a bit harder because the html elements it generates don't have IDs. If you're working with paragraphs/lists as a whole you could try `#HTML: <div style="direction:rtl">` before the paragraph, then `#HTML: </div>` after. (I haven't tried this) It's harder if you want rtl only on some span of text.

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax seems to be wrong. Instead of `#+ATTR_HTML: :dir:rtl` try `#+ATTR_HTML: :dir rtl`, that should work.

Comment: I tried this one before and it didn't work, but your answer made me doubtful of my trial, I tried it then once more but to no avail! sorry that didn't work with me, am I missing something?

Comment: I updated the post to reflect my point; that `#+ATTR_HTML: :dir rtl` didn't work.

Comment: @doctorate: My fault, ATTR_HTML is only meant for links and tables.